# Is there any way to download the audio from a certain page

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I am working on a  selenium script with python, and want to download the audio coming from a certain page.

the page looks like this :

[image]

the HTML code of the page :

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body>
<video controls="" autoplay="" name="media">
<source src="https://website//id=47c484fc7f8f" type="audio/mp3">
</video>
</body>
</html>
```

**my code so far:**

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver 
import sys
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time
import pyaudio
import wave
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options



chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
# for linux/Ubuntu only
#chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox") 


browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), chrome_options=chrome_options)
browser.get("website")
search = browser.find_element_by_id("text-area")
search.clear()
    
text = input("text here : ")
search.send_keys(text)
#print(data)
time.sleep(2)
browser.find_element_by_id("btn").click()

# Access and print requests via the `requests` attribute
for request in browser.requests:
    if request.response and request.url.__contains__('website//id'):
        browser.get(request.url)
```

I am open to work with any language to achieve the goal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need Selenium for this, requests library is enough. You must provide a unique identifier to your post request as sessionID, so you can pick up the generated file in the next get request.

Use the following snippet as an example, it saves the generated file under provided sessionID name.

```
import requests

sessionID = '78aa8dd0-9529-11eb-a8b3-0242ac130003'
payload = {'ssmlText': '<prosody pitch=\"default\" rate=\"-0%\">Roses are red, violets are blue</prosody>', 'sessionID': sessionID} 

r1 = requests.post("https://www.ibm.com/demos/live/tts-demo/api/tts/store", data = payload)
r1.raise_for_status()

print(r1.status_code, r1.reason)

tts_url = 'https://www.ibm.com/demos/live/tts-demo/api/tts/newSynthesize?voice=en-US_OliviaV3Voice&id=' + sessionID

try: 
    r2 = requests.get(tts_url, timeout = 10, cookies = r1.cookies)
    print(r2.status_code, r2.reason)

    try: 
        with open(sessionID + '.mp3', "w+b") as f: 
            f.write(r2.content)
    except IOError:
        print("IOError: could not write a file")
    
except requests.exceptions.Timeout as err: 
    print("Timeout: could not get response from the server")
```

Comment: it's working for one sentence, but when i try to insert a variable that contains more than a sentence (data[0:400]) it gives me this error :TypeError: string indices must be integers, and when i try to insert the variable like (data) it gives me error of timeout, when i increase the time it keeps looping and i get no result at the end, is there any way to solve it please.

Comment: Most probably the error comes from the conversion between html data and its string representation. Remember it should be a json eventually, thus it should not contain any improper symbols.

Comment: Also, please mind that a 10 000 symbols request results in at least 5MB audio file, thus taking more time, a bigger request can take up to several minutes. You might want to divide a big text into smaller chunks.

Comment: i'll try to give it more than 5 minutes and see what's gonna happen. the export_data() function is working fine and return a string containing sentences wanted from the html file.

Comment: i get this error after waiting  : 200 OK
504 Gateway Time-out

Comment: it's working now i had to turn my data into json format, i also had to reduce the size of it, i have one more question please: should i worry about the session id because i am going to run the script for several times?

Comment: If you pass the same session id, it overrides files both on the server and locally. If you want to keep those, you need to pass a new value on each subsequent request.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230735/discussion-between-adil-kasbaoui-and-eugene).